# Spring SAML Extension - Programmatically setting entityBaseURL

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using the Spring SAML extension with WSO2 IS as the IdP.  Currently I set the entityBaseURL property for the MetadataGenerator inside the Spring XML config.  For now, this works fine going against a single server since the entityBaseURL matches the servername.  Since I have several environments (dev, test, and UAT) I need to programmatically set the entityBaseURL because each environment has a different server name and that servername won't match the entityBaseURL prop.  It is undesirable to rebuild the WAR artifact for every environment.  We keep our config for each environment in a database.  So settings and properties specific to a particular stack of machines can be read at runtime.  I would like to read the servername for the entityBaseURL property from our DB and set it programmatically.  Should I replace the MetadataGenerator with my own class?  It is unclear to me where the entityBaseURL property is initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a workable path to solve this.  I ended up extending the MetadataGeneratorFilter class and overriding the getDefaultBaseURL method.  The default implementation of the getDefaultBaseURL method is to compute the value using properties found in the HTTP request.  I changed this behavior to do a DB lookup and return the value stored in the database.  I could be short-sited here, but this does work.  I was able to verify that the AssertionConsumerServiceURL attribute of the SAML AuthnRquest is getting set properly.  The generated metadata is also correct.

Note: the entityBaseURL property can still be set manually in the Spring config.  If it is then the value returned from the getDefaultBaseURL method is not used.